# Can a superadditive set function be upper-bounded by a measure?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Suppose $Q$ is a probability measure on a Euclidean space $\mathbf{E}$. Suppose $\mathcal{K}$ is the collection of all compact sets on $\mathbf{E}$.

Consider the function $f: \mathcal{K} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ defined as
$$f(K) = -\log(1 - Q(K)) $$
for every compact set $K$.

$f$ is a [superadditive set function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superadditive_set_function) in the sense that, given two disjoint $K_1, K_2 \in \mathcal{K}$, 
$$ f(K_1 \cup K_2) = - \log(1 - Q(K_1) -Q(K_2)) \geq -\log(1 - Q(K_1) - Q(K_2) + Q(K_1)Q(K_2)) = -\log((1-Q(K_1))(1-Q(K_2)) = f(K_1) + f(K_2). $$

My question is whether there exists a locally finite measure $\Lambda$ (not a probability measure) on $\mathbf{E}$ such that

$$ \Lambda(K) \geq f(K)$$

for all compact $K$.

If such a $\Lambda$ exists, then it must satisfy:

(1) $\Lambda(K) \geq Q(K)$ for all $K$ since $f(K) \geq Q(K)$.

(2) $\Lambda(\mathbf{E}) = +\infty$ since $f(K) \rightarrow +\infty$ as $K \nearrow \mathbf{E}$.

Yet, the tricky part is that $\Lambda$ is additive but $f$ is superadditive for disjoint sets.

I played around the case where $\mathbf{E} = \mathbb{R}$ and $Q$ being a standard Gaussian, but have not found a construction for such $\Lambda$.

Comment: Please be more precise --- what measures do you allow for $\Lambda$?  Possibly infinite on compact sets but determined by their finite values?

Comment: In what sense is there such a measure $\Lambda$ when $Q$ is supported on a singleton?

Comment: @user95282 Sorry for the confusion. Let us assume that $\Lambda$ is locally finite and $Q$ is supported on $\mathbf{E}$.

Answer (score 1):

(Edited once more, to eliminate extraneous symbols.)

There is such a measure, assuming $Q(K)<1$ for every compact set. The assumption holds if the support of $Q$ is the whole $E$.

Define $B_0=\emptyset$ and for $j=1,2,\dots$ let $B_j$ be the closed ball with center at the origin and radius $j$.
By the assumption $Q(B_j)<1$, hence $f(B_j)<\infty$, for every $j$.

Define constants $c_j$ for $j=1,2,\dots$ so that 
$$
c_{j} Q(B_j \setminus B_{j-1}) = f(B_j)- f(B_{j-1}) 
$$
(if $Q(B_j \setminus B_{j-1}) = f(B_j)- f(B_{j-1}) =0$ then choose
$c_j$ arbitrarily, for example $0$ or $1$).
The function $x\mapsto -\log(1-x)$ is convex, hence
$$
c_{j} Q(K\cap(B_j \setminus B_{j-1})) \geq
f(K\cap B_j)- f(K\cap B_{j-1}) 
$$
for every compact set $K$.
By summing that from $1$ to $n$ we get
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n c_{j} Q(K\cap(B_j \setminus B_{j-1}))
\geq f(K\cap B_n).
$$

Define the measure $\Lambda$ by 
$\Lambda(A) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j Q(A\cap (B_j \setminus B_{j-1}))$
for Borel sets $A$.
For every compact set $K\subseteq E$ there is $n$ such that 
$K\subseteq B_n $,
hence $\Lambda(K)$ is finite and
$$
\Lambda(K) 
= \sum_{j=1}^n c_j Q (K\cap (B_j \setminus B_{j-1}))
\geq f(K \cap B_n) 
= f(K).
$$

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure I understand these steps. (i) How does the existence such $\Lambda_j$ follow from the supermodularity of $f$? (ii) How did you get the inequality from convexity? By definition and superadditivity of $f$, $c_{j+1} \geq 1$. Are you using convexity with weights $c_{j+1} / (1 + c_{j+1})$ and $1 / (1 + c_{j+1})$? I cannot get what you have there with these weights. (iii) Why is $\Lambda = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j \Lambda_j$ locally finite?

Comment: @RichardGuo You were right about problems with the previous answer. They are corrected now, I hope.